# I have a download link, but when using python requests.get module, it does not download anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, python-requests, download

I have the following code but when I run it, in the terminal it keeps loading without showing errors or retrieving any data. I think it might be the link. How to get the XML file that appears when using the link on a browser?

```
import requests

def download_xml_file(url, save_path):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Check if the request was successful
        with open(save_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f"XML file downloaded successfully and saved at: {save_path}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error downloading XML file: {e}")

url = 'https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/GetEntityDownload.xml?type=G'
save_path = 'path/to/destination/file.xml'  # Specify the location where you want to save the downloaded file

download_xml_file(url, save_path)
```

I tried to run the code hoping to get the file attached to the link but literally the terminal did not show anything, it just kept running the script.

Comment: Try a general except clause as other error may be the issue: `except Exception as e`

Comment: What is the status_code of your url?

Comment: In the case of the exception, if I run the code withouth the try, except clause it does not return anything either. I will try that last solution.

The status code is "200 OK" According to https://websniffer.com/


Name Value
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Oracle-iPlanet-Web-Server/7.0
Content-Type: text/XML
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=results.xml
Server-Timing: dtRpid;desc="203970521", dtSInfo;desc="0"
X-powered-by: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
X-oneagent-js-injection: true
Content-Length: 28548102
Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 12:33:58 GMT
Connection: close

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The server does not like your headers for some reason so doesn't answer your request, obviously it would be better if it responded with 403 or something.

I tried with the following code and it works fine, because of the added header. You can add your own header or use this one(its old).

Most likely the only important one is the 'User-Agent'

```
import requests

url = "https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/GetEntityDownload.xml?type=G"

payload = {}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```